# Equivalent to Python’s findall() method in Ruby?

Tags: python, ruby, regex

I need to extract all MP3 titles from a fuzzy list in a list.

With Python this works for me fine:

```
import re
for i in re.compile('mmc.+?mp3').findall(open("tracklist.txt").read()): print i
```

How can I do that in Ruby?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
f = File.new("tracklist.txt", "r")
s = f.read
s.scan(/mmc.+?mp3/) do |track|
  puts track
end
```

What this code does is open the file for reading and reads the contents as a string into variable `s`. Then the string is scanned for the regular expression `/mmc.+?mp3/` ([`String#scan`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001711) collects an array of all matches), and prints each one it finds.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know python very well, but it should be

```
File.read("tracklist.txt").matches(/mmc.+?mp3/).to_a.each { |match| puts match }
```

or

```
File.read("tracklist.txt").scan(/mmc.+?mp3/) { |match| puts match }
```

Answer (score 0):

even more simply:

```
puts File.read('tracklist.txt').scan /mmc.+?mp3/
```